# Bibliography not generating

Tags: ubuntu, kile

I have a `.tex` where I am trying to cite a paper, but on compiling I found that it is not generating the bibliography.

[image]

I Tried compiling the `.tex` file as below but still nothing

```
PDFLaTeX
BibTeX
PDFLaTeX
PDFLaTeX
```

**Warning**

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `blei2003' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Citing \cite{blei2003}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

**ref.bib**

```
@article{blei2003,
author = {Blei, David M. and Ng, Andrew Y. and Jordan, Michael I.},
title = {Latent Dirichlet Allocation},
journal = {J. Mach. Learn. Res.},
issue_date = {3/1/2003},
volume = {3},
month = mar,
year = {2003},
issn = {1532-4435},
pages = {993--1022},
numpages = {30},
url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=944919.944937},
acmid = {944937},
publisher = {JMLR.org}
}
```

I am using `Kile 2.9.91` in `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: The example works for me as posted. There should be a `.blg` file after the BibTeX run. Can you tell us what it says? (I assume you have Kile call BibTeX and PDFLaTeX on the files. If you call the commands manually, make sure to run BibTeX on the basename of your `.tex` file (i.e. without extension) or on the `.aux` file).

Comment: @moewe In `.blg` file I got this message `I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst`, Its creating problem with `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` on the other hand with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` its working fine.

Comment: That suggests the file `IEEEtran.bst` is not installed. Did you get your TeX via the Ubuntu package repositories (`apt`/`apt-get`) or do you have a vanilla TeX live from TUG.org? If you have the Ubuntu repository version you may have to install the package `texlive-publishers`.